# Manifest merger failed error during build

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to build an app for API 7 which is the device I need to run it on.
I've set the minSDK to 7, and added the following:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    tools:ignore="OldTargetApi"
    tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.espresso,
                           android.support.v7.appcompat,
                           android.support.v4,
                           android.support.mediacompat,
                           android.support.fragment,
                           android.support.coreui,
                           android.support.coreutils,
                           android.support.graphics.drawable,
                           android.support.compat">
</uses-sdk>
```

However, during the (gradle) build I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 8 declared in library [com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2] C:\Users\david\.android\build-cache\828bf92787e99464e08501328373b997b66ab556\output\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.espresso" to force usage
```

Everything worked fine until I set the min sdk to 7 (it was 26).

What else do I have to do to get this to build? Thanks

Comment: You've still got a device running Eclair?

Comment: Yes, had it for a little while ;-)) It's a StorageOptions 7" Scroll Tablet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `android:minSdkVersion="7"` is a mandatory, you can try using the old version of espresso in your app `build.gradle` with the following dependencies:

```
 androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
```

You can found the version list in [Testing Library Support Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/release-notes.html)

Comment: Almost the same error - seems that v2.0 is built to API 8. Is there a version built to API 7?

Comment: The oldest version is `1.1`. Don't know if it's working with API 7, you can try it or just remove the espresso if you don't need it.

Comment: Tried v1.1 and got an error saying: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:1.1

Comment: Ok, I commented out the TestCompile entry and it builds ok. But when I try and run it I get another error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

Comment: That's a different error. Probably, you have multiple support library v4 dependencies in your `build.gradle`. Can you add the app `build.gradle` in your question?

Comment: Found a fix for this - I needed to add "multiDexEnabled true" to the gradle.

Comment: Yes, but it just creates more... Have posted another question about it.

Answer (score 0):

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 8 declared in
>   library

Your error is perfectly clear.Some of your included libraries configured to use with Minimum of SDK version 8.

Please **downgrade the libraries to 7** or **upgrade your App to 8**.

Comment: Actually, the error isn't perfectly clear (to me) or I wouldn't be asking the question.... I've added the line tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.espresso to force it (as suggested by Android Studio), but it is still compalining about it.

Comment: How do I downgrade the libraries? I'm not that familiar with Android or the Studio - I come from a VB and C# background.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this issue is resolved. As advised, I removed the reference to espresso, and found a solution to Dex problem on SO. Thanks to all who replied.